# Does deconstruction/removal regain used materials?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

The question might be trivial, but I found nothing in the wiki to support it.

I have a pair of water wheels constructed. I have a herbalist in a fey mood, and he requires wood and cut gems. I have embarked in a place that is now devoid of surface trees. Due to several reasons, I don't want to breach the cavern layers just yet and the nearest trade caravan is 2 seasons away.

Water wheels are made of wood, would deconstructing them give back the logs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! Deconstructing buildings gives back the raw materials used.

Source: experience playing the game. :P

Comment: For FUN, you can also embark with just enough materials to get started but have to successively construct and deconstruct buildings to succeed in the beginning. Ex: http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/v0.31:Sample_Starting_Builds#The_It-Do-Yourself_Steel_Option_weApon_Pair_Strategy_or_TIDYSOAPS

Comment: For FUN, I embarked on a map without any sort of weapon-grade ore and surface wood (which prevents for the time being to build up the military I need to explore the caverns). Just some [worthless yellow rocks](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Native_gold).

Comment: Felt dwarfy recently, built and deconstructed a floor, got all materials. Also was able to test with the water wheels, confirmed. Accepting.

Comment: An addition to the question would be does it give back the same resource used? Does deconstruction a bridge from mudstone bricks return mudstone bricks, and does a steel forge return a steel forge? I believe the answers to all these are yes.